# Brown spots appearing on roma tomato leaves

Tags: diseases, tomatoes

Three weeks ago I bought a roma tomato plant from Home Depot.  It was probably about 8 inches tall.  Since then, it was in my apartment for a few days and then my friend's apartment for about two and a half weeks (I was on vacation).  It has not been planted yet.

I live in New Jersey, and it's been pretty humid these last few weeks.

When I got the plant back today, I noticed some funny spots, as well as some leaves that were dying near the base of the plant.  The dying leaves are only on one branch.  The spots are on a few branches, mostly clustered together, but most of the branches are fine.  Pictures below.  What is happening to this plant, and what can I do to save it?

Extra information, as per a request: I will plant it in the ground.  The pot it is in now is about 6" across.  The sunlight it was getting in my friend's apartment was indirect: next to a window, but the window was facing north so never direct sunlight coming in.  I don't know how often or how much it was getting watered, but it was probably getting watered daily.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What size pot is it in now? How strong was the sunlight was it getting? How often and how much was your friend watering it? Also, are you going to plant it outside in a larger pot, or in the ground? (I'm originally from NJ, and grew tomatoes there.) I'm fairly confident that you can save it, but it would help if you answer these questions before I advise. You can just edit your post up above and add the info there so everyone will see it.

Comment: @Diane, the question is now edited.

Comment: @ Joshua- I still would go with Black Spot. Also, tomatoes need strong sunlight and larger pots. I've grown them in 5 gallon buckets and in the ground. Watered once or twice a week, until the water ran out the bottom. (They don't  like being teased by daily under-watering, which can cause blossom end rot.) Cut off the lower leaves AND the diseased leaves, leaving only a few upper leaves above the ground.  Bury the entire lower stem as deep as you can. It will sprout roots and make it stronger. Or gently bend the stem sideways and plant in a trench, with only the tops exposed.

Comment: Here's a link about the tomatoes. This is how all of my Italian/American   peeps NJ plant tomatoes. http://www.diynetwork.com/made-and-remade/make-it/plant-tomatoes-in-trenches

Comment: I've always started my cucumbers from small seedlings and then grown them in the ground on a trellis.  (I've never transplanted a potted cucumber that was as big as your plant.) I just researched it, and the planting directions for the larger cucumber plants looks very similar to those for tomatoes. Here's a link. http://homeguides.sfgate.com/plant-leggy-cucumber-seedlings-44067.html  If you determine that it is Black Spot on both plants, you will want to treat them, or consider buying new ones. It's discouraging to start with sickly plants.

Answer (score 1):

The first two photos look like Septoria leaf spot but the last photo looks like Early Blight.